# Using expression vector to express arsenite oxidase genes in E. coli

Tags: molecular-biology

So I am trying to express a gene cluster that can oxidize arsenite into arsenite autotrophically. The arsenite oxidase gene cluster sequence is linked here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY345225.3

I originally was going to clone this gene into the pBAD-DEST49 expression vector, and transform it into E. coli C600, but the vector is out of stock, and I need it quickly. I was looking through Sigma Aldrich, and I found this vector: PSF-OXB20. I plan to clone the genes into this vector.

I do, however, need some advice. I am not 100% sure on if this vector would work, or if the genes would be overexpressed. My question is would this vector work out, or is there any better ones out there. Any advice would be appreciated, and if I need to include more details, just let me know.